# Flux.jl GPU support for M1 Mac?

Tags: julia, flux.jl, flux-machine-learning

I am currently using a laptop with the M1 Mac chip. The Flux.jl docs only mention [support for Nvidia GPU's](https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/v0.12/gpu/). Is it possible to train my models using my local GPU or is there no support for the M1 Mac yet? Note: [Julia 1.7 beta 3](https://julialang.org/downloads/#upcoming_release) is currently being shipped with M1 Mac support so it seems like this would be feasible but I am not a GPU expert.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that there is much reason (so far) to support an 8 core GPU on the M1 when typical Nvidia CUDA core counts are in the hundreds or the thousands. That may change with future CPU's, perhaps.

Comment: As far as I understand, the M1 gpu is competitive with some Nvidia discrete gpus, at least older or moderate cards, such as the gtx 1050. I think 8 vs 'thousands' cores is too simplistic.

Comment: To be fair, there are 128 computing units useable on the 8 cores, so perhaps there really could be a speedup possible over the CPU cores.